# Position Dodge Function ggplot for regular plots R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, aesthetics

I'm trying to create a plot through the regular R plot function `plot()`
but I need to find a way to do something like `position = "dodge"` in `ggplot`.

I can't use `ggplot`, since I'm using a `cuminc` function, and it wont let me - unless I use `ggcompetingrisks()`, which just gives me bad aesthetics.

So far my code is:

```
plot(fit.CIF, fun=function(x) 1-x, ylab="Proportion of Uptake", xlab="Days", 
     lwd=3, lty=1, col = c("navyblue", "mediumorchid2", "brown", "tan3"), font = 2)
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I agree with @MrFlick. Also, you surely can use ggplot. It is a matter of producing the data first and then plotting, without using ggplot to do the summarizing.